# How to sort to-many key in core data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have created two entities called `Question` and `Answer` as follows:

[image]

Now, I save some data in both entities at some point in time. The code for that is working fine.

Now, I want to fetch question with its answers, so I use code as follows:

```
class func getAllQuestions(inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [Question] {

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Question")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "question_id", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor, answerDescriptor]
    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    if let questions = (try? request.execute()) as? [Question] {
        return questions
    }

    return []
}
```

As you can see that I have just wrote the code to fetch questions and I automatically got the answers related to specific answer.

**My Requirement:**

But when I get question and answers is automatically added to it, I want  answers to be sorted by display_order.

Can you please tell me, how can I add `NSSortDescriptor` to it?

**What I have tried?**

I have tried this sort descriptor:

```
let answerDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "answers.display_order", ascending: true)
```

But then I get runtime error:

```
<NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600000381110> , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)
```

Comment: You can sort answers when you use them on your code. As it is described in the error, you cannot sort questions based on answer's display-order.

Comment: That code is confusing. You're fetching a single `Question`, but you want to use a sort descriptor on the one result?

Comment: @TomHarrington I am not fetching a single question. I am fetching an Array of questions. When I get questions, I also want answers in each question to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a computed variable on `Question` like the following:

```
var sortedAnswers: [Answer] {
    let answerDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "answers.display_order", ascending: true)
    return answers.sortedArray(using: [answerDescriptor])
}
```

The `answers` relationship is always going to be unsorted. But this will let you get back a sorted array.

I think there’s another newer way to do this now, but I’m not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have implemented it as you told using computed variable and now it works fine.

Comment: @Vishal awesome